# How to make the card rotate after the condition is met automatically?

Tags: flutter, if-statement, flip, card

```
Widget buildTarget(CardItem? item) {
    if (item != null) {
      return Transform(
          alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
          transform: Matrix4.identity()
            ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.002)
            ..rotateY(pi*0.5),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: ClipRRect(
              child: Container(
                height: 150,
                width: 150,
                color: Colors.white,
                child:Center(child: Image.asset(item.imageUrl)),
              ),
            ),
          ));
    } else {
      return Text('Errors');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double _rotateFactor = 0.5;

void _changeAngle(double factor){
  _rotateFactor = factor;
  setState((){});
}

...

Widget buildTarget(CardItem? item) {
    if (item != null) {
      return Transform(
          alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
          transform: Matrix4.identity()
            ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.002)
            ..rotateY(pi*_rotateFactor),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: ClipRRect(
              child: Container(
                height: 150,
                width: 150,
                color: Colors.white,
                child:Center(child: Image.asset(item.imageUrl)),
              ),
            ),
          ));
    } else {
      return Text('Errors');
    }
```